# How call window.close on parent page but all button details define on child page

Tags: javascript, jquery

parent page and child page, In parent page I am using Iframe 
In child page I have multiple buttons and I want to write the button code in my parent page .
I can 't write any thing on child page.
I want to call window.close on button click .
after submit the data.
This button could be Approve button , reject button , cancel button.
So how I will call window.close in parent page ?

```
<html>

<head>

    <title>Parent Page</title>

</head>

<body>


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function openpopup() {

            var popper = window.open('Child.html', '_blank', 'width=400,height=400');

            popper.focus();

        }

        $(document).ready(function () 
{

            $("#youriframeid").contents().find("input[type=button]").on('click', function () { top.window.close(); })
        });

    </script>

    <iframe id="youriframeid" src="child.html" width="200" height="750" style="border: solid 1px #990000;" ></iframe>

</body>

</html>






<html>
<head>
    <title>Child page</title>

</head>

<body>


    <p>

        <input id="child" type="button"  value="Close [x]" />

        <div>

            <table border="1">

                <tr>

                    <td>Name</td>

                    <td><input type="text" title="Show"/></td>

                </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td>Address</td>

                    <td><input type="text" title="Show" /></td>

                </tr>

            </table>

        </div>

    </p>


</body>




</html>
```

Comment: Could you please explain whether you want to open your 'Child.html' page either in an iframe or new window. 
Because I can see openpopup() method defined in parent page but you are not calling it from any one. Also you are trying to open your 'Child.html' from window.open method and from an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

### Parent Page:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var popper;
    function openpopup() {
        popper = window.open('Child.html', '_blank', 'width=400,height=400');
        popper.focus();
    }
    window.CallParent = function () {
          popper.close();
    }
</script>
 <input id="btnopen" type="button"  value="Open" onclick="openpopup();" />
```

### Child Page:

```
<p>
    <input id="child" type="button"  value="Close [x]" onclick="opener.CallParent();" />
    <div>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>Name</td>
                <td><input type="text" title="Show"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Address</td>
                <td><input type="text" title="Show" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</p>
```

Comment: actually we can not add anything on close button i.e - onclick

Comment: without using on click on child page how we can access this button on parent page for window.close .

Comment: <html>

<head>
    <title>Parent Page</title>
</head>

<body>

    
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var popper;
        function openpopup() {
            popper = window.open('Child.html', '_blank', 'width=400,height=400');
            popper.focus();
        }
        window.CallParent = function () {
              popper.close();
        }
    </script>
     <input id="btnopen" type="button"  value="Open" onclick="openpopup();" />
     <input id="child" type="button"  value="Close [x]" onclick="CallParent();" />
</body>

</html>

Comment: all buttons are in child page . we have to access these button child page to parent page without using onclick , id , class.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>Parent Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>

  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <iframe id="youriframeid" src="child.html" width="400" height="250" style="border: solid 1px #990000;" ></iframe>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('#youriframeid').load(function(){
            var iframe = $('#youriframeid').contents();
            iframe.find("input[type=button]").click(function(){    
                    alert("0");
            });
    });
  </script>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Comment: If we are using  iframe.find("input[type=button]") .It will be applicable in all button .. Exp : we have one form in child page and we have to submit this page with all details. First all form data with be submit on server after that window.close function will be execute. I also used this button but before submit the the form details this button works